# ng new issue - unable to scaffold a new angular app

Tags: javascript, angular

I've just updated the angular-cli

If I check the terminal with ng -v this is what i get:

```
 Angular CLI: 1.6.1
 Node: 8.6.0
 OS: darwin x64
 Angular: 
 ...
```

When I try to scaffold a new angular application with the following command

```
ng new my-app
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: obs.pipe is not a function
obs.pipe is not a function
```

I've tried to install and uninstall the cli several times but still I can't solve the issue.

Comment: This isn't something SO can help you with - see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8941 and check your RxJS versions.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue 8941 is not that helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error when using the following command

```
ng g module <module-name>
```

Turns out my problem was a mismatch between the global angular cli version and the local one. Running

```
npm install -save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

solved it for me. (I ran it in the parent directory to the project I was using, but it should work in the same directory also).